# c++: Split string by delimiter

Tags: c++, arrays, string, split

For example I have this string: `hello:there:world`

How do I split these three words to string array,
I mean the final result will be this:

```
arr[0] = "hello";
arr[1] = "there";
arr[2] = "world";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c